# Groovy: how to call closure in top scope from another closure

Tags: groovy, jenkins, closures, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to break up code that makes use of the Jenkins Job DSL plugin into reusable pieces, and I suspect that my question is generic to Groovy and not Jenkins-specific.  For example, I want to reuse parts of this block:

```groovy
freeStyleJob() {
    //generic stuff
    name "something"
    description "something else"

    //custom stuff
    scm {
       svn {
           //etc....
       }
    }
}
```

By placing name and description in a utility method (obviously I want to do more than just that in real life).  However, I cannot find the proper syntax to create a closure for the current scope.  Here is how I think it should look:

```groovy
def jobCommonItems() {
    return {
        //generic stuff
        name "something"
        description "something else"
    }
}


freeStyleJob() {
    jobCommonItems().call()

    //custom stuff
    scm {
       svn {
           //etc....
       }
    }
}
```

(Perhaps with a closure.delegate = this somewhere)

However, that's not working for closures.  It is working for methods, as illustrated here: https://dzone.com/articles/groovy-closures-owner-delegate

To illustrate, here is a test that shows three combinations of possible syntax:

```groovy
String myString = "Top Level: string"
def myMethod() {
    println "Top Level: Method"
}
def myClosure = { println "Top Level: Class"}

class MyClass1 {
    String myString = "Class1: String"
    def myMethod() {
        println "Class1: Method"
    }
    def myClosure = { println "Class1: Closure"}
}

class MyClass2 {
    String myString = "Class2: String"
    def myMethod() {
        println "Class2: Method"
    }
    def myClosure = { println "Class2: Closure"}
}

class MyClass {
    def closure = {
        println "In-Class generated closure begins, delegate is ${delegate}"
        myMethod()
        myClosure()
        println myString
    }
}

def closure = new MyClass().closure
closure.delegate = new MyClass1()
closure()

closure = new MyClass().closure
closure.delegate = new MyClass2()
closure()

// This fails - it can find the top level method, but not closure or string
closure.delegate = this
closure()



def methodMissing(String methodName, args) {
    println "Method not found in class ${this} by name ${methodName}"
}
```

I get an error that the closure is not in the main class (ie test for test.groovy): Method not found in class test@60611244 by name myClosure

I've tried changing delegate to "this", I tried changing the lookup strategy, etc.   I'm probably missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The job factory methods like `freeStyleJob` return an object that can be used to apply more configuration using the `with` method. That method expects a closure argument which has the same properties as the closure passed to the `freeStyleJob` method.

```
def basicConfiguration() {
    return {
        description('foo')
        scm {
            // whatever
        }
    }
}

def myJob = freeStyleJob('example') {
    publishers {
        // more config
    }
}
myJob.with basicConfiguration()
```

The script itself is an instance of `DslFactory` which is the interface containing e.g. the `freeStyleJob` method. You can pass that object to classes or methods to use the `freeStyleJob`.

```
def myJobFactory(def dslFactory, def jobName) {
    dslFactory.freeStyleJob(jobName) {
        description('foo')
    }
}

def myJob = myJobFactory(this, 'example')
```

And then you can use the `myJob` object to apply further configuration using `with`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that one solution is to invert the relationship like this, and to pass "this" as the context to find DSL top-level closures.

```groovy
class Utils {
    static def makeMeABasicJob(def context) {
        context.freeStyleJob() {
            //generic stuff
            name "something"
            description "something else"
        }

    }
}

def job1 = Utils.makeMeABasicJob(this) //Passing the groovy file class as the resolution context
job1.with({
    //custom stuff
    scm {
        svn {
            //etc....
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
def jobCommonItems(job) {
    job.name = "something"
    job.description = "something else"
}

freeStyleJob() {
    jobCommonItems(this)

    //custom stuff
    scm {
       svn {
           //etc....
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work.  I get the same "No signature of method" error for the items broken out into a separate method.  (All except for description, which works for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

When trying to extract out common logic from my Jenkins DSL groovy script, I originally used the style of passing the **job** object to a common static helper, and then doing `job.with{...}` similar to daspilker solution.

However I found using delegates a little more straight forward.
For example:

```
freeStyleJob('name') {
    jobDesc(delegate, 'something')
    jobSCM(delegate, 'git@gitlab.com:MyGroup/MyProject.git', 'master')
}

def jobDesc(def context, def descText) {
    context.description(descText)
}

def jobSCM(def context, def repoURL, def branchName)
{
    context.scm {
        git {
                remote {
                    url(repoURL)
                }
                branch('refs/heads/' + branchName)
        }   
    }
}
```

The **jobDesc** and **jobSCM** method could be moved to a separate utility class as static helpers, which you would then import into your DSL groovy script.